# Every time I wish to run a java program, java applet pops. How to get the new program be executed and displayed in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

Every time I wish to run a java program, java applet pops up with a solution of previous program. How to get the new program be executed and displayed in console?

Comment: Right click over your Eclipse project or over the class that contains your main method: `Run As > Java Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the little down arrow on the run button and click "Run configurations..." and on the left side delete the one with the name of your class. Now run it again and a window will pop up. Select "Java application" and it will run just fine.